# Follow on instagram from android and handle OAuthPermissionsException

Tags: objective-c, instagram

i am using this link

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user-id]/relationship?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

in the above link user_id is the id of the person to whom i want to follow and Access token is created for my app in instagram developer site.

and it give response like

```
{
   "meta":
   {
     "error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException",
     "code":400,
     "error_message":"This request requires scope=relationships, but this access token is not authorized   with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=relationships to be granted write permissions."
   }
}
```

i searched on internet and some one told me to  add scope=relationships while creating access token i don't know how to do this..

**Simple Words**

Follow a Instagram user on click of a button .

Answer (score 0):

scope=likes+comments+relationships+basic

use it then you are trying to login

"To request multiple scopes at once, simply separate the scopes by a space. In the url, this equates to an escaped space (“+”)."

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/